# How to aggregate queries in firebase

Tags: firebase, nosql

when i used to work with Ms SQL server i used to create for example this query

```
Select Sum(Amount * Price) from table
```

- Can this be done in GOOGLE FIRE BASE this is so important before i start a new project
- Note there will be more queries like that

> How can we run such queries and how complex it can be

I relay need to either choose fire base or use normal SQL server to work on the project

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore does not support native aggregation queries. However, you can use [client-side transactions or Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) to easily maintain aggregate information about your data.

Cloud Firestore provides powerful [query functionality](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) for specifying which documents you want to retrieve from a collection or collection group.

You can also chain multiple where() methods to create more specific queries (logical AND). However, to combine the equality operator (==) with a range or array-contains clause (<, <=, >, >=, or array-contains

[Cloud Firestore does not support the following types of queries:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)

- Queries with range filters on different fields, as described in the previous section.
- Logical OR queries. In this case, you should create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app.
- Queries with a != clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example, although the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported, you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause where("age", ">", 30).